Will applying a mold encapsulant (Sentinel 24-7) onto studs cause any degradation of its structural integrity?
There is a mold encapsulant product called Sentinel 247 that has 100% worked for my mold issues.  Absolutely love it. This product keeps all moisture out of the wood for decades.  The main ingredient is zinc omadine. Comes in clear, no color, transparent.
We have applied it to the wood studs (the wood big structural beams behind the Sheetrock/drywall of the house).
I am concerned that maybe the wood can’t “breathe” and the product will dry out the wood, causing the studs to lose structural integrity.
But then I am thinking, painting is done all the time on exterior wood to PREVENT rot.  But then again, I don’t know how it affects important STRUCTURAL wood like wood studs.
Will an encapsulant like this dry out the wood too much so that the structural integrity of the wood studs is negatively affected, or will the wood be fine since it’s just a coating?

Wood doesn't breathe. (And nor does it need to be fed, another bit of flowery language the finish industry loves to use to manipulate the public.) Wood does however naturally take on or lose moisture as the external moisture levels go up and down — i.e. with changes in humidity — but it doesn't need to and preventing it does no more harm than permanently positioning wood in a climate controlled environment, or encasing it in resin as with a thick bartop-type coating. FWIW I am highly, highly, doubtful that this product does completely prevent moisture uptake and loss anyway [contd]

...the way that it'll work instead is that it is a potent anti-fungal agent, as are some other surface coatings, and its chemistry just interferes with the biology of fungi (and bacteria too possibly) at a biological level.

As you said, this is like painting wood, so it’ll be fine, assuming the wood wasn’t wet when the product was applied. (Wood doesn’t need to breathe… it naturally finds ‘equilibrium moisture content’, and this product appears to slow that moisture movement.)
